# Dash when using radians in physics

Tags: siunitx

So I have a number that is in units of millimeters-milliradians. Typically, it might be expressed as mm-mrad. How do I get that dash using siunitx?

Comment: Could you please add an MWE? Do you want a dash between two numbers? What is the current delimiter between the two? Or is there any way to recognize the two parts? We can not help you unless you elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[inter-unit-product=\mbox{--}]{1}{\mm\milli\radian}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That said, are you sure you want a dash in there? It doesn't really make sense, and the few texts I saw after a (very quick) search has mm mrad, or possibly a multiplication sign between the two.

Comment: It's something of a convention in accelerator physics. I haven't totally decided whether to follow the convention or leave it behind.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of terms expressed in units of millimeters-milliradians, you could set up a new "unit" for them, using the `\DeclareSIUnit` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mmmrad}{\milli\meter\textrm{-}\milli\radian}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\mmmrad}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you could also set up new new unit as follows:

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\mmmrad}{mm\textrm{-}mrad}
```

Note the use of `\textrm` to get a short "dash" symbol rather than a long "math minus" symbol.

That said, I'd like to echo @TorbjørnT.'s comment that you may want to rethink the presence of a dash symbol in this unit. Might an ordinary thinspace be more appropriate?